Is it possible to make the rule match only the outermost obj and not the ones inside it?
Is it possible to make the rule match only the outermost obj and not the ones inside it?, I read the ast-grep documentation, and it seems it can be achieved using stopBy. this is a playground of rule
expect: 2 match
// match 1
{
    a: 1,
    b: {
        c: 1
    }
}

// match 2
{
    d: 1,
    e: {
        f: 1
    },
    g: {
        h: 0
    }
}


You can use not + inside + stopBy: end.

not: https://ast-grep.github.io/guide/rule-config/composite-rule.html#not
inside: https://ast-grep.github.io/reference/rule.html#inside
stopBy: https://ast-grep.github.io/guide/rule-config/relational-rule.html#stopby

rule:
  kind: object
  pattern: $A
  not:
    inside:
      kind: object
      stopBy: end

Example Playground

thanks for the explanation,learned❤️

I applied this rule to the sgroot node and found some sgnodes. But when I try to apply this rule to the sgnodes to recursively find the next level of nodes, it doesn't work. Why is that?

use a rule by @ast-grep/napi, this is demo of github demo

Eventually, I solved it by re-parsing. parse(children.text())
